# how to create a grouped bar chart in streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

how to create grouped bar chart in Streamlit
I have tried st.altair(chart) method to get the answer but still it shows the stacked bar chart instead of grouped bar chart

Comment: iscuss.streamlit.io/t/how-to-graph-a-grouped-bar-chart-on-streamlit/17957/3

Comment: i have tried these methodss still doesnot work

Comment: Can you share the code for what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to [create the bar chart with Altair](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2002#issuecomment-597064355) and then just pass it to Streamlit:

```
chart = alt.Chart(prediction_table2, title='Simulated (attainable) and predicted yield ').mark_bar(
    opacity=1,
    ).encode(
    column = alt.Column('date:O', spacing = 5, header = alt.Header(labelOrient = "bottom")),
    x =alt.X('variable', sort = ["Actual_FAO", "Predicted", "Simulated"],  axis=None),
    y =alt.Y('value:Q'),
    color= alt.Color('variable')
).configure_view(stroke='transparent')

st.altair_chart(chart)
```